# intent to specific activity when push notification clicked in.

Tags: android, android-intent, push-notification, android-notifications, intentservice

Not opening specific activity on notification click when the app is in background/not running

The notification-click starts specified activity only when the app is opened up and the notification-click is performed. If the app is in background/not running and the notification-click is performed, the application's MainActivity opens up. In short, it is like the app opens normally following the activity stack instead of opening the specified activity in the PendingIntent.

**Firebase Instance Id Service:**

```
package com.example.tamzid.pushnotification;

 import android.util.Log;
 import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceId;
 import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdService;

 public class MyAndroidFirebaseInstanceIdService extends 
FirebaseInstanceIdService {

private static final String TAG = "MyAndroidFCMIIDService";

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    //Get hold of the registration token
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    //Log the token
    Log.d(TAG, "Refreshed token: " + refreshedToken);
}
private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
    //Implement this method if you want to store the token on your server
}
}
```

**Firebase Message Service:**

```
 package com.example.tamzid.pushnotification;

 import android.app.NotificationManager;
 import android.app.PendingIntent;
 import android.content.Context;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.media.RingtoneManager;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
 import android.util.Log;
 import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
 import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;

 public class MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService extends FirebaseMessagingService     
{
private static final String TAG = "MyAndroidFCMService";
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    //Log data to Log Cat
    Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
    Log.d(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " +     
remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
    //create notification
    createNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
}

private void createNotification( String messageBody) {
    Intent intent = new Intent( this , ResultActivity. class );
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    PendingIntent resultIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity( this , 0, 
intent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

    Uri notificationSoundURI = 
RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mNotificationBuilder = new 
NotificationCompat.Builder( this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("Android Tutorial Point FCM Tutorial")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel( true )
            .setSound(notificationSoundURI)
            .setContentIntent(resultIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager)  
getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, mNotificationBuilder.build());
 }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.tamzid.pushnotification">

<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".ResultActivity"></activity>
    <service android:name=".MyAndroidFirebaseMsgService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service android:name=".MyAndroidFirebaseInstanceIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" 
/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: you used getNotification() which workd only when app is in foreground. you need to use getData() to do that

Comment: when app is in background, your public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) never called. System handle notification so you can not specify custom activity there. if you use Data() then you can do whatever you want

Comment: oky,,sir ......

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `remoteMessage.getData()` instead of `remoteMessage.getNotification()`

> Use `remoteMessage.getNotification()`: if message contains a
>   notification payload.
>
> Use `remoteMessage.getData()`:if message contains
>   a data payload.

**Update `onMessageReceived()` as below:**

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) 
    {
        //create notification
        createNotification(remoteMessage.getData().toString());
    }
}
```